# iTunes for Windows won't un-pause

Tags: itunes, windows, bug

I am running iTunes on Windows 10 to play my personal music collection.

Oftentimes if I pause the music it won't un-pause. I click the button, which changes to the "playing" icon, but the progress bar doesn't start moving and no music plays. Clicking repeatedly doesn't do anything. The only thing that does is quitting iTunes and restarting from where I left off, which is obviously annoying.

Anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: Which version of iTunes? Make sure you have the latest version.

Comment: @NoahL It's 12.4.3.1 I'll upgrade to the new on now and see what happens...

Comment: Problem persists after upgrade to latest version of iTunes.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling iTunes completely and installing from scratch?

Comment: @Brian Actually the problem has vanished as mysteriously as it started.